# connect failed: ECONNREFUSED issue on few Anfroid Devices

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-ksoap2, ksoap

I have developed an Android Application which consumes a Webservice. I have tested the application on different devices and its working perfectly but on the tablet of my client, it's throwing an exception. All devices on which application is tested are running Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow.Following is the exception

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to web.abc.com(port 80):connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Following is my code for consuming Webservice

```
String namespace = "http://web.abc.com/";
private static final String url = "http://web.abc.com/WebService/ServiceFileName.asmx";

String SOAP_ACTION;
SoapObject request = null, objMessages = null;
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport;

/**
 * Set Envelope
 */
protected void SetEnvelope() {

    try {

        // Creating SOAP envelope
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        //You can comment that line if your web service is not .NET one.
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        //envelope.addMapping(namespace, "ProductStausResponse",new ProductStausResponse().getClass());
        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("Soap Exception", e.toString());
        System.out.println("Soap Exception---->>>" + e.toString());
    }
}

// MethodName variable is define for which webservice function  will call
public String getProductStatus(String MethodName, String Parameter)
{

    try {
        ProductCode = ProductCode.trim();
        SOAP_ACTION = namespace + MethodName;

        //Adding values to request object
        request = new SoapObject(namespace, MethodName);
        /// Code for setting properties

        SetEnvelope();

        try {

            //SOAP calling webservice
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            //Got Webservice response
            String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            //e.printStackTrace();
            //return "Exception";
            return e.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("Soap Exception", e.toString());
        //return "Exception";
        return e.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have internet permission in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, Application has Internet Permissions in manifest.

Comment: can you show entire stacktrace?

Comment: Extremely Sorry, I can't provide stacktrace because the the client is far away from me and I am unable to produce this bug on my side.